# Problema con la librería PHPExcel

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que no se pongan toda la hoja de Excel con los bordes si no solo las columnas de la hoja.Estoy usando PHPExcel para exportar una tabla dinámica en CodeIgniter. Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Os dejo el codigo que me marca toda la hoja:

```
 $styleArray = array(
            'borders' => array(
                'allborders' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                )
            )
        );


        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle('')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Y como me exportar el documento con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahora estoy en el móvil y no puedo buscarlo en mi ordenador pero deberías tratar de usar phpspreadsheet en lugar de phpexcel

Answer (score 0):

De momento no estas especificando de donde a donde

Debes hacer algo similar ha esto

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8:H8')->applyFromArray($styleArray);